# How to make a paint class that doesn't get called twice?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

I wrote a paint class, and added the jpanel to the frame, but it's getting called twice for some reason, as I put a print statement inside the graphics method, and it printed it twice. The codes below are all the codes I have in my package.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Paint extends JPanel {

static Paint paint = new Paint();

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(500, 500);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    System.out.println("Hello");

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(paint);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocation(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

}
```

Comment: Code seems it prints Hello only once.

Comment: I tested it and it works as it should (only prints it once). Are you running it from an IDE? Try doing it from the command line and see if it's the same. Maybe it's a focus issue.

Comment: It's called whenever it has to be. If you want to do drawing process only once, you can draw it on an offscreen image and then draw the image when `paintComponent` is called.

Comment: I tried it both on a portable eclipe and on a non-portable netbean. both is printing hello twice. @GabrielNegut

Comment: Try running it from the command line instead of an IDE (doesn't matter if it's portable or not).

Comment: What does it mean if it works from the command line? What do you mean when you said "focus issue"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and `paintComponent` it's not called twice every time. I don't think you have the control on when the JFrame is calling pack() when you call `setVisible`. It may depends on how your OS manage the windows.

Comment: I'm using a portable eclipe.

Comment: It's not the IDE which runs your code. On eclipse or others IDE the result will be the same.

Comment: I think it's normal. It's like when you resize the JFrame : paintComponent is called several times.

Comment: But, I'm not resizing it. I just runs it, and did not do anything else, and yet it prints hello two times?

Comment: As I said, it's the JFrame which decided when she called your paintComponent method. If  you want to have the control you may need to rewrite the JFrame class.

Comment: So it just decided to run it twice for no reasons?

Comment: I think it's because you explicitly call pack().
The first called to paintComponent is when you add the JPanel in the frame. And the second is when you called pack.

Comment: removing pack() makes it print hello 3 times.

Comment: So just admit it's JFrame which manage the called of this function and you cannot predict it.

Comment: So, basically it's a freaking bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: It's not a bug, paintComponent is called every times the jframe consider that she need to render it's content because it has changed. So when you run your app, maybe your OS trigger some event on you jframe that cause the jframe thinks the content need to be refresh.